# Converting 64bit strings into jpeg with javascript/css

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, 64-bit, jpeg

In order to avoid firefox's aggressive de-caching/garbage collection of large images we've been experimenting with ways to store references to images. Keeping references to 'new Image()' objects seems to work, but uses a lot of memory.

I'm now experimenting with using

```
$.ajax({
   url: "http://localhost/360/img/frames/compressed/frame0470.jpg",
   dataType: "text",
   success: function(r) {
      console.log(r);
   }
});
```

to retrieve the image's base64 string (which presumably can be stored in less memory than the image object and won't be subject to firefox's image garbage collection). But how can I convert this back into a jpeg?

Comment: I assume you mean base64. And what you get as a response is the text representation of an image. not base64. But however, what you're trying to do sounds like a bad idea. Handle caching serverside with expirations.

Comment: @binarious - It's possible I'm wrong on this as I haven't researched too deeply, but it seems that in recent versions, firefox has implemented an aggressive garbage collection feature whereby images (even if they are currently being used by a web page in an unfocused tab) are regularly removed from memory (presumably for performance gains). Maybe 'caching' isn't the term I should be using - I'll amend the question to reflect this

Comment: @binarious Well, it's way too aggressive. On our current page we're preloading some images to be shown in sequence. As there's no direct inclusion of the image in the css/html, unless we store it in an `Image` object the image will often get garbage collected before it appears on screen. I haven't timed it, but firefox really doesn't wait very long (less than a second it looks like) before assuming the image is ok to be discarded. I'll play around with expires headers though to see if it improves things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really get the reason you want to achieve either, but you should be able to get binary data in XHR rather than confine yourself in types supplied by jQuery.

First, read MDC docs here to retrive proper binary string of the image
https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Receiving_binary_data_in_older_browsers

Second, the binary string can be converted into base64 by `window.btoa()`.

Third, base64 image string can be displayed by constructing data url. I am sure you already know how to do it.

Compare to the actual binary data, binary string cost 4x more memory since each character in the string is actually 4 bytes in memory as Javascript uses UCS-2 internally. Base64 string costs 4*1.3=5.2x more memory. Base64 data is 130% bigger than the original data.

A neat way to deal with binary data in Javascript is to work with the Blob object. But I failed to see anyway to get a Blob displayed as an image, so ...

If you want to avoid the aggressive image eviction, I think the possible approach is to paste the image to a <canvas> element and display it.

<canvas> actual comes with a built-in function `toDataURL()` that provide the data you want, but if you get away with the image eviction then you don't need it.

Comment: That's two answers in a post! Try both of them and tell me the result!

Comment: In the end we went for storing images we'd need to use soon in Image objects and implementing our own garabage collection utility to make sure a minimal number of images were stored, but your answer looks good. If I ever need to use base64 image strings I'll revisit this.

Comment: The above link is broken, the correct one is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data#Receiving_binary_data_in_older_browsers

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get the reason you want to achieve that, but to answer your question:

**Basic idea:**

You need to encode that data to Base64:

```
var base64Data = Base64.encode(r);
```

Display Base64 Image:

```
$('<img>') // create new image
    .attr('src', 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + base64Data) // set image data as b64
    .appendTo('body'); // add the image tag to the body element (or any other)
```

But practically it seems a bit more complicated: http://emilsblog.lerch.org/2009/07/javascript-hacks-using-xhr-to-load.html